# Processing midi notes in real time

Tags: java, midi

Basically, I want to get and display the data of a midi note (the track, the note, and the octave) as a sequencer plays it, in real time.

I'd like to be able to add this to the following code:

```
Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.setSequence(MidiSystem.getSequence(song));
sequencer.open();
sequencer.start();
while(true) {
    if(sequencer.isRunning()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Check every second
        } catch(InterruptedException ignore) {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ControllerEventListener to the Sequencer. It will save you the active wait and will provide all the information you need to display.

```
ControllerEventListener controllerEventListener = new ControllerEventListener() {
   public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
      // TODO convert the event into a readable/desired output
      System.out.println(event);
   }
};

Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
int[] controllersOfInterest = { 1, 2, 4 };
sequencer.addControllerEventListener(controllerEventListener, controllersOfInterest);
```

Have a look at this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-seq-adv.html) as well.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working, for some reason, could I be using a bad midi?